# Transparent background in Eclipse?

Tags: text-editors, eclipse, themes, transparency

Is there a way to make the background of [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) text editor transparent? I would like to adjust the alpha transparency of the background, but have the text still be opaque. Perhaps there is a plugin that accomplishes this? I haven't seen any options under preferences. And my search on Google has ended in vain thus far, although I did find some nice [color themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/).

Example (Textmate):

[image: Transparent Textmate]

Note that the text is still solid. This is important, since making the whole window transparent could cause text to bleed into the desktop wallpaper (or whatever is under Eclipse).  I'm interested in solutions for all platforms that Eclipse runs on.

Related question:

- [Eclipse fonts and background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. However, Java 7 which is expected as of July 28th, 2011 has [support for translucent windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html). After that, Eclipse is community effort... your best bet is to either to [participate in development](http://www.eclipse.org/contribute/), or consider programming Eclipse plugin (or find someone interested in progamming plugin).

Comment: according to that link, it may indeed be possible as of Java 6 Update 10. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Josh, you are right - I was reading the note above that documentation is updated for Java 7, and didn't see the smaller note which is actually accurate. So, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Transparency ide is possible on any IDE/Text Editor with WindowTop Pro version that can be downloaded from here:
https://windowtop.info/

Images real transparency as the user asked:
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-QpC7DZAlE

Use version 3.4.5 and above. This feature was just started to be stable from version 3.4.5. In addition, this is very new and you must have Windows 10 update 2004.

In addition, the feature is based on an algorithm that does image processing & recognition and for this feature to work right, you must have Cuda enabled GPU that is NVIDIA GPU with CUDA support.

More information here:
https://windowtop.info/2020/05/07/how-to-make-your-ide-or-code-editor-with-transparent-background/

Full Disclosure: I am the developer of this product. This feature can work on any IDE, Text editor of any kind.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not exactly what you ask, but an obvious solution would be to use eclim system to make Eclipse available to macvim/terminal vim and make that transparent.

For macvim the option is to set to 20%

```
set transparency=20
```

It might be even possible to swap the editor inside eclipse for macvim, but I am less sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free application called [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) that has the ability to make windows transparent (and much more). I would check that out.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora, you could use Compiz to make it transparent (Video tutorial on how to do just that [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1rTlA8B5yE).) In both Fedora and Windows, what about setting a transparent image as the background?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get the effect you are looking for.

Eclipse uses [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) as its windowing toolkit, and if I remember correctly it has limited support for transparent and translucent windows. This support is probably limited to the entire window and not parts of it.

SWT uses a class Shell that is the actual window, creating a Shell with the flag NO_TRIM will cause it to have transparent background. As this window is created by the Eclipse platform I doubt that it is possible to access it via a plugin.

If you feel like building a plugin translucent support could probably be achieved by accessing functions in the native toolkit directly (either the WIN32 API or the GTK API) and applying them to the Eclipse components. As I have limited knowledge of Eclipse plugins I can't direct you to any particular starting place for creating such a plugin. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use compiz in Ubuntu, and most other linux distributions for making the windows transparent.